# Отправка писем на почту

Tags: php

Скажите пожалуйста, обязательно ли подключать SMTP-сервер что бы отправлялись письма автоматически пользователям с сайта? Допустим зарегистрировался пользователь и ему письмо приходило о успешной регистрации. Объясните пожалуйста, я в этом вопросе новичок так что нужна ваша помощь) на денвере письма успешно появляются в папке tmp/!sendmail а вот залил скрипт на хостинг бесплатный протестировать на hostinger.ru так письма не приходят.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете скачать готовое решение, к примеру, PHPMailer, и использовать его.
Если у вас бесплатный хостинг вы можете использовать SMTP от gmail, либо любого   другого почтового сервера, что предоставляет такие услуги.

Answer (score 0):

> обязательно ли подключать SMTP-сервер что бы отправлялись письма

нет

> вот залил скрипт на хостинг бесплатный

на бесплатном и к SMTP подключиться не получится.

Comment: просто на том хостинге он есть

Comment: значит надо протестить на нормальном хостинге ?